# Attach one time event to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a web page where there is a button, when the button is clicked a Textbox is added to a DIV. Here is a similar code that I'm working with:

HTML

```
<button class="addText">Add Textbox</button>
<div class="textCont">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on("click", ".addText", function() {
    var textarea = $("<textarea/>", {class: "newText"});
    $(".textCont").append(textarea);
});

$(document).one("focus", ".newText", function() {
    alert("Great");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErRohitAgg/g3A7T/

What I'm trying to do is to show an alert for first focus of every textbox that is added. But, instead the focus event is executing only once, and not once for each Textbox.

Is there  any way the event behaves according to the functionality I need??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event handler to each textarea instead

```
$(document).on("click", ".addText", function() {
    $("<textarea/>", {
        'class': 'newText',
        one    : {
            focus: function() {
                alert("Great");
            }
        }    
    }).appendTo(".textCont");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3A7T/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it by adding newclass on first focus:

```
$(document).on("focus", ".newText", function() {
if(!$(this).hasClass('focused')){
  $(this).addClass('focused')
  alert("Great");
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7c3a3/)**